# NullPointerException in a Sokoban project - Java - OOP

Tags: java, oop, object, nullpointerexception, stack

I am experiencing problems all the times with NullPointerExceptions, so I thought I could use some good explanation.

The game is more or less complete as my assignment requires, but as a extra I wanted to add undo- logic.

I thought I could implement a stack to hold the Level object, then pop it if the players wants to undo their move. Following I would make a new level with a toString method which returns the Level object as a String which could then be used to make another Level to add into the stack.

I guess the `Level b = new xx` is wrong, whereas the new xx equals null...

Here is my code:

```
public class Sokoban {
    private Level level;
    private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private Deque moves;

    public Sokoban(){
        //initialize level. PS Klarer du denne er du god!!
        moves = new ArrayDeque();
        moves.push(new Level("    ######\n    #@#  #\n  ###$   #\n###   $$ #\n#.   $  ##\n#.. $#  # \n#.#  #### \n#.####    \n###       "));
        level = (Level) moves.peek();
        level.display();
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){ //!level.finished()
            String nextInput = sc.next();
            if (nextInput.equals("r")){
                Level a = (Level) moves.pop();
                level = new Level(a.toString());
                level.display();
                moves.push(level);
            }
            Level b = (Level) moves.peek();
            level = new Level(b.toString());
            level.move(nextInput);
            level.display();
            moves.push(level);
        }
        //System.out.println("Congratulations, you did it!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sokoban sokoban = new Sokoban();
        sokoban.run();
    }
}
```

EDIT2: http://pastebin.com/0ChHwkgH full code, 3 classes.
       http://gyazo.kennethd.net/i/PPzJC.png - console call

Comment: For what line does it give the exception?

Comment: 32 -  level.move(nextInput);

Comment: In your conditional statement of the run() method, maybe you need to also test if nextInput is null or not.  if(nexInput != null && nextInput.equals("r"))  If it is null, you'll need to break out of the loop.  I don't see any break statement and you could potentially have an endless loop condition.

Comment: Also, for best practice, you should write:
if ("r".equals(nextInput)){  // Avoid nullPointerException from here

Comment: @Alan Implementing it did not make any difference, but I suppose it's good practice?

Comment: Which of the variables is NULL?  nextInput or level? Test for both so we can narrow down the culprit.

Comment: level is null, I've checked that nextInput isn't null in many cases and it did not reference null before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the following two things:

1) Use generics for the Deque:

```
 private Deque<Level> moves = new ArrayDeque<Level>();
 //etc...
```

2) Ensure you overwrote the *toString()*-method in Level, so that the level returns its representation in a String similar to the one used in the constructor:

```
new Level("    ######\n    #@#  #\n  ###$   #\n###   $$ #\n#.   $  ##\n#.. $#  # \n#.#  #### \n#.####    \n###       ");
```

**EDIT:**

```
        while(true){ //!level.finished()
        String nextInput = sc.next();
        if (nextInput.equals("r")){
            Level a = (Level) moves.pop();
            level = new Level(a.toString());
            level.display();
            moves.push(level);
        }
        // It is possible that peek returns null (it's the case if the deque is empty)
        // but this should only be an hint
        Level b = (Level) moves.peek();
        level = new Level(b.toString());
        level.move(nextInput);
        level.display();
        moves.push(level);
    }
```

I think the main problem is, that the method which calculates the number of rows and columns of your field fails and therefor the initialization of the workerLocation-array in the Level-class is skipped. So if you try to access it the first time a Null Pointer Exception occures. Try to get the values of rows amd columns in the Level-class.

Comment: Thanks! I actually had the toString()-method wrong, it added an extra \n at the end of the String. However it's still giving the NPE at `level.move(nextInput);`.  

`Level b = moves.peek();
System.out.println(b.toString());` I checked that this does actually return a valid string, it is exactly the same as the one passed in in the constructor.

Comment: Could you share your Level-class?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/NeSyxCLf - feel free to suggest better practice, if you got spare time of course :) Also, check out the edit to the main post. And is this approach even "good" at all? :)

Comment: I edited my previous post. There is a problem with the deque, because the _peek_ can return null. Also there is a Problem with the Level class.

Comment: It seems the peek never returns null, however you are right about the rows and columns, during the second initialization, rows are 1, and columns are -1. Will try to find the reason :)

Comment: You should edit your post and add the code for the rows and columns count.

Comment: I think I've isolated the bug. The String passed into the Level constructor isn't treated as one line, but the newline characters are applied. Any solution how to stop this behavior?

Comment: The code you uploaded runs perfectly fine. I didn't get a NullPointerException. Also the String is interpreted just fine.

Comment: Are you serious? Could you share a sample console output? I get lots of errors when copying the code you used into the project, replacing my old. if i type s, sout(rows) equals 1, and sout(columns) equals -1.

Comment: It works! Don't know how though, but thanks for your help! Much appreciated :)